Monitoring Databricks Assistant activities with system tables not returning any results
To monitor Databricks Assistant activities using system tables, you can query specific system tables designed for this purpose. These tables store activity logs that track various metrics, such as queries executed by the assistant, performance metrics, and user interaction data. For example:
SELECT * 
FROM system.access_logs 
WHERE user LIKE '%Assistant%'

However, I get the following error when I execute the code.
[TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view `system`.`access_logs` cannot be found. Verify the spelling and correctness of the schema and catalog.
If you did not qualify the name with a schema, verify the current_schema() output, or qualify the name with the correct schema and catalog.
To tolerate the error on drop use DROP VIEW IF EXISTS or DROP TABLE IF EXISTS. SQLSTATE: 42P01

This is strange because I can see the table is there

Any thoughts on why I'm getting the error?

Can you try with 3-level namespaces?  ex: select * from system.billing.usage
